# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6

this is my Class to cash the currently logged user
when i am getting this error but i can figure it out while searching the error i am not  getting any idea.my model class have the property 
public virtual User User{get;set;}

```
public static class Auth
{
    private const string UserKey = "BlogwithEf.Auth.UserKey";
    public static User User {
        get
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return null;
            var user = HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] as User;
            if (user == null)
            {
                var db= new Database();
                user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                if (user == null)
                    return null;
                HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] = user;
            }
            return user;

        }
    }
}
```

this is my controller code

```
[HttpPost,ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult New(PostsNew form)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(form);

        var post = new Post
        {
            User = Auth.User,
CreatedAt=DateTime.UtcNow,
Title = form.Title,
Slug = form.Slug,
Content = form.Content
        };

        //Error is here

        Database.Posts.Add(post);

        Database.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a separate object to store the user in the session, so the session object is not an db object. create a SessionUser class with all the properties you need and store this object into the session.

add a UserId property to your post object and fill in the UserId field of the post instead of the User object. EF should recognize the UserId as an FK to User.